# Android Studio load file from resources

Tags: java, android, junit, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying load .json files from resources so I can use them in unit tests.

I have created a resources file and marked it as a ‘resources root’ directory, and placed my .json files within it. As the files are to be used for tests only, I do not wish to place them in the /res directory as it unnecessarily bloat the app.

I am attempting to open the resources file with the following code, however `inputStream` returns as null.

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                          .getResourceAsStream("file.json”);
```

I have set the following in the .iml file that should denote the directory as resources but it seems to have had no effect.

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I maybe going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why was this marked down? Seems a reasonable and well described issue regardless of ones thoughts on his desire to put resources out of the res directory. The ability to mark different sources as resources should, at first glance, support his requirements.

Answer (score 2):

you can use assest folder or raw folder under resource folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the files are only for the purpose of running unit tests, I do not wish to place them in the android res folder. So I have created a resources directory in the tests directory

Comment: @Smalesy - what you want takes a back seat to what Android provides.  To achieve your goal, you will have to work with the supported building blocks - either package the data in the apk as suggested here, or transfer it over the network at runtime or push it to the external storage with ADB.

Comment: He can use the assets folder rather than res (and its a better batch) (just to correct the typo in answer above) this isn't under res but admittedly doesn't address his "want".

Comment: For tests use `/src/androidTest/assets/` or `/src/test/assets/`.

Answer (score 2):

When the APK file for the app is built, it does not include directories that you create outside of "res" and "asset".  Only files inside the APK are deployed to the device or emulator when testing.  So there is no way to test a file that you do not include in the APK.

Files that are placed in the tests directory do not seem to be accessible. So AFAIK, you'll have to put the file in the app APK and then remove it later.  Or, even better, it is possible to use gradle to produce a version of the app APK for testing and a different one for release.  The release version could exclude the file.